# How to get current committing message of tortoise svn to a c# windows application

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, message, commit, sharpsvn

How can I get current committing message of tortoise svn  to a c# windows application using sharp svn API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: I got the answer for this